# Angular charts not working with Angular 5, Showing below error attached screen shot

Tags: angular, chart.js

{
"name": "cm",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"serve": "ng serve",
"start": "concurrently --kill-others "npm run start-server" "npm run serve-json"",
"build": "ng build",
"cloud": "bash ./src/ng.sh build --prod --aot=true --env=cloud --build-optimizer=true",
"uat": "bash ./src/ng.sh build --prod --aot=true --env=uat --build-optimizer=true",
"prod": "bash ./src/ng.sh build --prod --aot=true --env=prod --build-optimizer=true",
"uat-prod": "npm run ng-high-mem build --prod --aot=true --env=uat --build-optimizer=true",
"ng-high-mem": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
"start-server": "ng serve",
"serve-json": "json-server -p 5000 ./src/assets/db.js",
"serve-mock": "concurrently --kill-others "nodemon ./mock/server.js" "ng serve --env=mock"",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e",
"compodoc": "./node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json -d docs/"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.1.1",
"@types/simple-peer": "^6.1.5",
"angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.6.3",
"angular-google-charts": "^2.2.2",
"angular2-counto": "^1.2.5",
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
"exceljs": "1.12.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"intl": "^1.2.5",
"lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"moment": "^2.19.2",
"ng-otp-input": "^1.7.1",
"ng2-charts": "^2.2.0",
"ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.0",
"node-gyp": "^8.4.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.4",
"simple-peer": "^9.1.2",
"symbol-observable": "^1.2.0",
"videogular2": "^6.2.0",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"xlsx": "^0.16.3",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/core": "^0.8.1",
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.5",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.0.1",
"@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.0.5",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~8.0.51",
"codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
"concurrently": "^3.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"json-server": "^0.12.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"nodemon": "^1.12.0",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "^2.7.2",
"underscore": "^1.8.3"
}
}

Comment: You gave nothing that we can help you with, you only shared your package.json, no code or any errors

Comment: i am getting ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function while implementing ng2-charts. I tried with Below versions but nothing is helping. Thanks in advance.
ng2-charts : 2.2.0 & 2.2.5 & 2.2.4 & 2.4.2
Angular : 5
"chart.js": "^2.9.3",

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls share the code - component.ts where is implemented the chart ?

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function while implementing ng2-charts.
```

Because this clearly indicates a problem in the code (in your component). Bad implementation, or use of a method, etc .... but we have to see the code so we can help.

Comment: barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {responsive: true};
      barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010'];
      barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
      barChartLegend = true;
      barChartPlugins = [];
      barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
       { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
       { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' },
       { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series C' }];

Comment: <div class="col-md-12" style="display: block;">
                <canvas baseChart 
                  [datasets]="barChartData"
                  [labels]="barChartLabels"
                  [options]="barChartOptions"
                  [plugins]="barChartPlugins"
                  [legend]="barChartLegend"
                  [chartType]="barChartType">
                </canvas>
              </div>

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://www.encodedna.com/angular/how-to-create-bar-chart-in-angular-4-using-chartjs-and-ng2-charts.htm

Comment: in app.module.ts I have added import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts'; module

Comment: ng2-charts.js:226 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at eval (ng2-charts.js:226)
    at Object../node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js (vendor.bundle.js:9335)
./node_modules/ng2-charts/fesm2015/ng2-charts.js @ vendor.bundle.js:9335
eports.module.ts @ main.bundle.js:4078
./src/app/government/government-account.module.ts @ main.bundle.js:3800
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
eval @ app.module.ts:47
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1

Comment: added error message in above comment

Comment: Nodejs : 10.15.0 i am using (is node version is fine)